# Drag layer with table

Tags: javascript, drag, layer

I am trying to drag a layer on a PC platform and also a mobile device. I can do this, but with the following issue. When a table is inside the , I cannot drag from within the table. The table will drag with the layer, but only if clicking outside the table. My code snippet highlights the issue.

```js
// Works with mobile  
var dragItem = document.getElementById("item");
var container = document.getElementById("container");

var active = false;
var currentX;
var currentY;
var initialX;
var initialY;
var xOffset = 0;
var yOffset = 0;

container.addEventListener("touchstart", dragStart, false);
container.addEventListener("touchend", dragEnd, false);
container.addEventListener("touchmove", drag, false);

container.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart, false);
container.addEventListener("mouseup", dragEnd, false);
container.addEventListener("mousemove", drag, false);

function dragStart(e) {
  if (e.type === "touchstart") {
    initialX = e.touches[0].clientX - xOffset;
    initialY = e.touches[0].clientY - yOffset;
  } else {
    initialX = e.clientX - xOffset;
    initialY = e.clientY - yOffset;
  }

  if (e.target === dragItem) {
    active = true;
  }
}

function drag(e) {
  if (active) {

    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.type === "touchmove") {
      currentX = e.touches[0].clientX - initialX;
      currentY = e.touches[0].clientY - initialY;
    } else {
      currentX = e.clientX - initialX;
      currentY = e.clientY - initialY;
    }

    xOffset = currentX;
    yOffset = currentY;

    setTranslate(currentX, currentY, dragItem);
  }
}

function setTranslate(xPos, yPos, el) {
  el.style.transform = "translate3d(" + xPos + "px, " + yPos + "px, 0)";
}

function dragEnd(e) {
  initialX = currentX;
  initialY = currentY;

  active = false;
}
```

```css
#outerContainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  left: 200px;
  top: 100px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  z-index: 100;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 200px;
  touch-action: none;
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  order: inherit;
  zindex: 200;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  touch-action: none;
}

#table1 {
  display: flex;
  width: 200;
  border: 2;
  align: center;
}

#item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #333333;
  z-index: 5;
  display: flex;
  cursor: move;
  justify-content: center;
  touch-action: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#item:active {
  background-color: rgba(168, 218, 220, 1.00);
}

#item:hover {
  cursor: move;
}

body {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerContainer" style="position:absolute; z-index:100">
  <div id="container" style="position:absolute; z-index:10">
    <div id="item" style="position:absolute; z-index:1">
      <br/>Can drag from here<br/>and from here
      <br/>
      <table id="table1" border="2" bgcolor="#00CC66">
        <tr>
          <td>This is in the table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cannot drag from here</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `When a table is inside the , I cannot drag` What word or tag is missing here?

Comment: You could try add position:relative; to table. Or make it not clickable... pointer-events: none;

Comment: The word missing was the dragable div.

Comment: Thanks. pointer-events: none; solved the problem.